# Array Splitting in bash

Tags: bash

This following piece of code for constructing a sub array gives the output -

```
sdf,sdf,sdf,sdf
sdf,sdf,sdf,sdf
```

But the expected output should be

```
sdf,sdf,sdf,sdf
sdf,sdf
```

What is wrong with the code?

```
 #!/bin/bash

    ary=("sdf","sdf","sdf","sdf")
    team_one=( "${ary[@]:0:2}" )
    echo "${ary[@]}"
    echo "${team_one[@]}"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, you don't need to use commas.  Arrays in Bash are space-delimited; not comma-delimited as is the case in some languages, such as javascript.

So your code should look something like this:

```
arr=("a" "b" "c" "d")
team_one=("${arr[@]:0:2}")
echo "${arr[@]}"
# a b c d
echo "${team_one[@]}"
# a b
```

The problem with your code was that `"sdf","sdf","sdf","sdf"` in an array is treated as one big long string rather than as four instances of the string `sdf`.